# Bootstrap dropdown not working with input-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a dropdown input to use as a search box. I want it to work similarly to the Stack Overflow tag box. You search for users, it pops up suggestions, you click on one, it populates with that choice and activates a button you can then use to cancel that choice and start the process all over again.

Everything's working pretty okay, except when I added the button in a [Bootstrap input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), the dropdown box stopped dropping down. It simply doesn't display now.

Here's the html:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="dropdown">

            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="entryInput form-control" id="query" name="query" type="text" data-toggle="dropdown" {{#if session "queryPopulated"}}readonly{{/if}}/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="cancelQuery" class="btn btn-default" type="button"
                    {{#unless session "queryPopulated"}}disabled{{/unless}}>X</button>
                </span>
            </div>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="query">
                {{#each queryResults}}
                    <li><a class="result" data-id="{{_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there an option I can set that will link the two up again? This behavior worked fine (well, almost fine, check out [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285537/bootstrap-input-dropdown-change-activation-behavior) to see why it isn't perfect) until I put things in the input group. Is that just something I can't do? Am I getting too greedy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the attribute `data-toggle` on the `input`, you should set it on the `input-group`.

It works for on this bootply : http://www.bootply.com/120440

**Code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="input-group" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <input class="entryInput form-control" id="query" name="query" type="text"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="cancelQuery" class="btn btn-default" type="button">X</button>
                </span>
            </div>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="query">
                    <li><a class="result" data-id="{{_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="result" data-id="{{_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="result" data-id="{{_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="result" data-id="{{_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="result" data-id="{{_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a></li>
                    <li><a class="result" data-id="{{_id}}">{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should check out this other issue I'm having. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285537/bootstrap-input-dropdown-change-activation-behavior